# Cashfree Payment gateway Integration in react native and laravel (orderAmount is required error)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native

I am integrating CashFree payment gateway in react native app (Android). I am following this documentation https://docs.cashfree.com/docs/react-native-2-0-sdk#web-checkout. While implementing I am getting response as

```
{"type":"CashFreeResponse","txMsg":"orderAmount not provided","txStatus":"FAILED"}
```

But I am passing all the params what all required to proceed for payment.

```
  const handlePayment = response => {
    console.log('amount', total);
    var mode = 'TEST';
    var map = {
      "appId": response.credentials.app_id,
      "orderId": response.credentials.order_id,
      "orderCurrency": 'INR',
      "orderAmount": 150, //parseInt(response.data.price)
      "customerPhone": response.user.mobile,
      "customerEmail": response.user.email,
      "tokenData": response.payment_info.cftoken,
      "orderNote": 'Subscription Payment',
      "notifyUrl": '',
      "customerName": response.user.name,
    };
    console.log('data', map);
    RNPgReactNativeSDK.startPaymentWEB(map, mode, result => {
      console.log(result);
      var obj = JSON.parse(result, function (key, value) {
        console.log(key + '::' + value);
        // Do something with the result
      });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Documentation mentioned on their website you need to enter the order amount as a string.

```
  const handlePayment = response => {
    console.log('amount', total);
    var mode = 'TEST';
    var map = {
      "appId": response.credentials.app_id,
      "orderId": response.credentials.order_id,
      "orderCurrency": 'INR',
      "orderAmount": '150',
      "customerPhone": response.user.mobile,
      "customerEmail": response.user.email,
      "tokenData": response.payment_info.cftoken,
      "orderNote": 'Subscription Payment',
      "notifyUrl": '',
      "customerName": response.user.name,
    };
    console.log('data', map);
    RNPgReactNativeSDK.startPaymentWEB(map, mode, result => {
      console.log(result);
      var obj = JSON.parse(result, function (key, value) {
        console.log(key + '::' + value);
        // Do something with the result
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180455/how-to-soul-payment-gateway-using-stripe-error-in-react-native